# Can you pull the emails collected through a "form" and dump them into a Civi CRM group?

Tags: civigroup

If I create a form that will collect email addresses, can those email addresses be exported or added to a Civi CRM group for later mailings?  I am trying to find a way to collect emails on the front end of our website then add them tour interest group mailing list on the back end without having to manually create a new contact that will then be able to be added to the group.

Comment: It might help figure out which of below answers is helpful if you can clarify if everyone who is completing your form is being added to your mailing list, or only those who opt-in. For everyone, then Mick's answer is probably most helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to SE!  There are several ways to add email addresses to a mailing list. See [this section](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/email/set-up/#allow-people-to-sign-up-for-your-mailing-lists-online) in the User Guide.

What CMS are you using?  On Drupal, you can use webforms.  On WordPress you can use Caldera Forms or Contact Form 7

The [GDPR extension](https://docs.civicrm.org/gdpr/en/latest/communication-preferences/) also provides a page for people to choose which groups they want to belong to.

Comment: Thank you, we have used Caldera forms in the past but we end up inputting by hand the information from that list.  We are thinking of using the profile option on Civi, thanks for you help!

Answer (score 3):

You can do all this with a profile. It has options in the advanced section to create a contact from the form and also to add the contact to a specific group. If you are wanting sign to multiple groups you will need to explore one of the other answers.

Comment: Thank you I think the profiles will work great!

Answer (score 2):

A couple of other ideas to add to Aidan's suggestions.

If you make your Group 'public' and then add the Group field to a profile, the Group will be listed for folk to tick. (it will list all 'public' groups, so if you only have one then you are sorted)

You can also just add a custom field eg 'newsletter sign up' = 'yes' and then build a Smart Group

Comment: Thank you for that idea, I will look into this as option as well!